# How to use ssh2 in PHP 8.0?

Tags: php, ssh2

I read through all the incompatibilities prior to installing php 8 updates only to find out way too late that there is no support for the ssh2 extension yet that I can find.  I am hoping that I am just missing something.  I have been googling for a couple hours and all possible leads came up dry.  Can anyone point me to the php 8 version of ssh2 extension, please?

Comment: [This PECL extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.2) claims to be supported by _"PHP 8.0.0 or older_". See _"Dependencies"_ at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I downloaded that 1.2 version and there is nothing mentioning PHP 8 except that dependency notation.  Since I do not know how to compile the source into a useable extension, I am left to wait until they release a proper extension for 8.0.  I don't think it exists as of yet...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they've released this extension for PHP 8+. [PECL Download](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I saw it go by in Ubuntu updates as well.  I have not had the chance to evaluate and had rewritten a ton of code temporarily so I was sort of letting it age a tad.  I appreciate the heads up though.  I'll come back here and post my results once I get a chance to evaluate...

Answer (score 0):

### Install "libssh2-1-dev" Package on Ubuntu

Quick Install Instructions of libssh2-1-dev on Ubuntu Server. It’s Super Easy! simply click on Copy button to copy the command and paste into your command line terminal using built-in APT package manager.

See below for quick step by step instructions of SSH commands, Copy/Paste to avoid miss-spelling or accidently installing a different package.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libssh2-1
```