# Forge Laravel ssh2

Tags: php, php-extension, laravel-forge, ssh2

I'm hosting a wordpress site on forge laravel. In one of my files I want to use ssh2_connect. But the ssh2 php module isn't installed. The site is running on PHP 8.0.

I've tried to install it through different commands in my terminal via ssh. But when I'm running the command php -m | grep shh2 it doesn't return anything. I've added extension=ssh2.so to the php.ini, but then I'm getting the error: PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module.

Can somebody help me with the correct commands to run? My knowledge with this kind of stuff is minimal so some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Wordpress currently has only [beta support](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/references/php-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/) with PHP 8.0, I suggest you use PHP 7.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ssh2 in PHP 8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712574/how-to-use-ssh2-in-php-8-0)